# Vite proxy server rewrite

Tags: vue.js, vite

```
/**
 * Generate proxy
 * @param list
 */
export function createProxy(list: ProxyList = []) {
  const ret: ProxyTargetList = {};
  for (const [prefix, target] of list) {
    const isHttps = httpsRE.test(target);

    // https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy#options
    ret[prefix] = {
      target: target,
      changeOrigin: true,
      ws: true,
      rewrite: (path) => path.replace(new RegExp(`^${prefix}`), ''),
      // https is require secure=false
      ...(isHttps ? { secure: false } : {}),
    };
  }
  console.log('proxy list');
  console.log(ret);
  return ret;
}
```

I have above method to create a list of proxy based on different prefix which defined in .env.development.

```
VITE_PROXY = [["/basic-api","http://127.0.0.1:3100"],["/api","http://127.0.0.1:8080"],["/upload","http://localhost:3300/upload"]]
```

But when I request url http://127.0.0.1/api/xxx, it is not rewrite to http://127.0.0.1:8080 as expected.

then I just add return path in rewrite function like this:

```
rewrite: (path) => 
        {path.replace(new RegExp(`^${prefix}`), '');return path},
```

Then it works.

I am confused now. What's the difference there? I googled a lot about vite proxy rewrite, normally, no need to add return statement like I just did.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: `rewrite: (path) => {path.replace(new RegExp(`^${prefix}`), '');return path},`
will return you the original, untransformed path, since `replace` returns a new string. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace.

So probably the regex or underlying logic is not correct.